# Error in web.xml "Element -- is not allowed here"

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I have a problem in my `web.xml`. I get the following errors element is not allowed here.

Here is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <description>MySQL Test App</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mobile</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I get error in this line.

```xml
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mobile</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and in this line.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And that's not all, whenever I startup the project (using Tomcat 8), I don't get any compilation errors. My web application starts up like it's normal. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Solved the problem! You just had to restart the IDE and now it works for some reason, strange.

Comment: I have the same problem... I am using IntelliJIDEA 2016 ...

Comment: Au contraire, stackoverflow overlords.  This one was resolved in a manner that DID help a future reader.  For those insufficiently sure they haven't made a web.xml coding error, being made aware that IntelliJ can be the culprit and that in that case restarting IntelliJ will fix the problem is very helpful.

Comment: Occurred on Android Studio as this day of post...restart AS and the problem was gone as user3612244 suggested