# Intellij Idea autocomplete not correct for web xml file

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, xsd, web.xml

I am using the following header in my `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but Idea is unable to suggest correct syntax for `web.xml`. I am getting the below.

[image]

I have the following in my `pom.xml` so I am sure the JAR file is correct.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I understand that the autocomplete should be working as per the XSD file. So is the XSD being used incorrect?

Comment: it seems that it's a problem of IDE, which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: @Bob.Z IDE version is 14.0.2

Comment: try to restart IntelliJ and see if OK.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519685/error-in-web-xml-element-is-not-allowed-here

Comment: @Bob.Z Make that an answer. It's really silly that all the refresh in IDEA did not help but a restart did.

Comment: Really strange, I ever met similar situation and ended it up with restarting IDEA, perhaps there exists some unknown bugs, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think its your schema fault.Use following schema, it is working fine for me

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">![enter image description here][1]
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: But that makes it web.xml 2.4 but I thought the syntax is valid in web.xml 3.1 also.

Comment: It mustn't an issue of schema, I have tried the version which @Aseem Bansal provided.